# Beveling deforms the object in a specific place

Tags: edges, bevel

I did apply scale. Here's what happens:

[image]

It only happens with few specific edges. Others behave well.
Are they ripped?

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks to me like you've got a face pretending to be an edge. I've had similar bugs before. In face select mode, do you see a dot in the center of the edge, indicating a selectable face ? If not, maybe it's a flipped normals problem but it doesn't really look like it.

Comment: yes maybe flip normals or a face inside your mesh?

Comment: Gosh, they were flipped: https://i.imgur.com/z0q9QFj.jpg Of course, didn't even think of that. Thanks guys!